# Problema de conexion a la BD

Tags: php, mysql

Saludos les escribo por que tengo un probelma con mi conexion ya que me arroja los siguintes errores:

```
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\trabajos\aula\01\admin\dbcon.php on 

line 2

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\trabajos\aula\01\admin\dbcon.php on line 4
```

Y este el código php de conexión

```
<?php mysqli_select_db('aulavirtual');
mysqli_connect('localhost','root','0000')or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); ?>
```

espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Claramente el error muestra que no se le estan enviando los parametros y es debido a que la función debe recibir 2 parametros como dice.

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','0000','aulavirtual') or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($conn,'aulavirtual');
$conn->mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba así:

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','0000')or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($conn,'aulavirtual');
mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
?>
```

O mejor así:

```
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','0000','aulavirtual') or die(mysqli_error());
$conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
?>
```